# IRS ACA Sample Manifest AATS sample file

Tags: xsd, irs

I need a sample file for the latest Scenarios of AATS Testing. We generated the code for this and want to check the against to accepted one.

Comment: I have already checked the boomtax and they are reference to old one.

Comment: The latest scenarios have been added to the BoomTax site.

Answer (score 1):

"Latest scenario" is always changing. More importantly, why don't you just submit your XML and see what response you get from the IRS? If they accept it, there's no need to do anything else. If they reject it, they will indicate where it failed. Either way, there's no need to see anybody else's XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current scenarios and answer keys for the scenarios for AATS testing at the following link:

https://www.irs.gov/for-tax-pros/software-developers/information-returns/affordable-care-act-assurance-testing-system-information

**Edit:**
Be sure to review the "AATS Scenario Known Issues and Solutions" link. As of this post, that document was last updated on 4/26/2016 and mentions some issues that have been reported and solutions for them.

Comment: i already have that sample files with me the current one which i need is the XML files. I have already generated XML files but not yet submitted to AATS Environment.